# How to format List items into different row of table for every new value of users

Tags: c#

I have four lists for four columns of a table. I want to print data as shown in the screenshot of the image below.

However, whenever I run the code below details of first user come according to the screenshot but after I input another user's data and try to print it, it comes in same line like this:

`Jack Li Tom smith 10 5`

This is what I have tried:

```
 public void SummaryTable()
        {

            Console.WriteLine("\tSummary of Membership Fee");
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1,10} {2,10} {3,10}","Name", "Weeks","Discount","Charges");
            //Console.Write("Weeks\t");
            //Console.Write("Discount\t");
           // Console.WriteLine("Charge");
            //Console.WriteLine();

            foreach (string namesl in nameList)
            {
                Console.Write("{0}",namesl);
                //Console.Write("\t");
            }

            foreach (int weekl in weekList)
            {
                Console.Write("{0,10}",weekl);
                //Console.Write("\t");
            }

            foreach (string discountl in discountList)
            {
                Console.Write("{0,10}", discountl);
               // Console.Write("\t");
            }

            foreach (double chargel in chargeList)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0,10}",chargel);



            }
```

[image]

Comment: Because you only have `Console.WriteLine` in the last loop. If there are no items in `chargeList`, that code will never be executed and everything will appear on the same line because everywhere else you have `Console.Write`.

Comment: Create a specific class to hold your User information, and expose a single List of type User, which has information regarding the name, week, discount, charge. 
Then you will be able to have a single foreach loop, which will print all the information.

Right now, using multiple foreach statements, goes against what you are trying to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could just print them like this:

```
Console.WriteLine("\tSummary of Membership Fee");
Console.WriteLine(new String('=', 45));
Console.WriteLine("{0,-20} {1,-5} {2,-10} {3,-10}", "Name", "Weeks", "Discount", "Charges");
Console.WriteLine(new String('-', 45));

for (int count = 0; count < nameList.Count; count++)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0,-20}{1,5}{2,10}{3,10}", nameList[count], weekList[count], discountList[count], chargeList[count]);
    Console.WriteLine(new String('-', 45));
}
```

Comment: I found this as the simplest way to do so. Yes It worked perfectly :-) Thanks

Answer (score 2):

### These are parallel lists

I believe what you have here are called parallel lists. The first item in the first list goes with the first item in the second, third, and fourth lists; the second item in the first list goes with the second item in the other lists; etc. Is that correct?

What is needed here is to merge the lists into one, which you can do several ways. Here is a simple and intuitive way to do it. I'll show two:

### Crayon method

This method is very simple and intuitive, although not all that fancy.

First, define a class that can contain the data in a single object:

```
public class Member
{
    public string Name     { get; set; }
    public int    Week     { get; set; }
    public string Discount { get; set; }
    public double Charge   { get; set; }
}
```

Then write a bit of code to merge your four lists into a single list of Member objects:

```
public List<Member> GetMergedList()
{
    var results = new List<Member>();

    for (int i=0; i<nameList.Count; i++)
    {
        results.Add(
            new Member
            {
                Name = nameList[i],
                Week = weekList[i],
                Discount = discountList[i],
                Charge = chargeList[i]
            }
        );
    }
    return results;
}
```

Now you can just iterate over (or `DataBind` against) the single list:

```
    public void Run()
    {
        var members = GetMergedList();
        foreach (var m in members)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\r{2}\t{3:0.00}", m.Name, m.Week, m.Discount, m.Charge);
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
John    1 Discount1    1.23
Paul    2 Discount2    4.56
Dave    3 Discount3    7.89
```

### Using LINQ

You could also merge your lists using LINQ (e.g. using the [Zip](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267698(v=vs.110).aspx) method) to produce an anonymous type that contains everything:

```
        var membersViaLinq = nameList
            .Zip(weekList, (n, w) => new { Name = n, Week = w })
            .Zip(discountList, (x, d) => new { Name = x.Name, Week = x.Week, Discount = d})
            .Zip(chargeList, (x, c) => new { Name = x.Name, Week = x.Week, Discount = x.Discount, Charge = c });

        foreach (var x in membersViaLinq)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\r{2}\t{3:0.00}", x.Name, x.Week, x.Discount, x.Charge);
        }
```

This approach is a little more confusing to read, but the benefit is you don't have to define a class just to hold the data.

### The best solution

The best solution is to retrieve the data in a single list to begin with, if possible, and completely eliminate the parallel lists entirely. To suggest a way to do that, I'd have to see your data retrieval code.

[Full example code on DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/DWpGBR)

Answer (score 1):

This is easily solvable using **OOP**.

Create a following class:

```
public class Person 
{ 
    public string firstName; 
    public string lastName; 
    public int weeks;
    public bool discount;
    public int charge;
}
```

Now instead of creating multiple lists you will create only one list:

```
List<Person> People = new List<Person>();
```

You can populate it with `Person` objects.

Example:

```
People.Add(person1);
People.Add(person2);
People.Add(person3);
People.Add(person4);
```

Here I'm assuming you are going pass in a list of persons as an argument to this function:

```
public void SummaryTable(List<Person> list)
{
    foreach (Person p in list)
    {
        Console.Write("{0}", p.firstName);
        Console.Write("{0}", p.lastName);
        Console.Write("{0}", p.weeks);
        Console.Write("{0}", p.discount);
        Console.Write("{0}", p.charge);
    }
}
```

Now you simply call the function:

```
SummaryTable(People);
```

Also make sure you import the required namespaces `using System.Collections;`.